# How can i add a V or something on a MenuStrip that show me when i clicked on this menu?

Tags: c#

I have a MenuStrip for example i have in the menu a tab called: Check Test
I want to do something that when i click once on the Check Test it will do something bu also will add some V or some sign near to it on th menu so i know that this menu is now active and another click will remove the V from it or near it.

Not a checkBox but something like a checkBox somehow to add a V or something near or on the menu when i click on it.

Comment: Something that will notify the user that he chose or clicked on this menu maybe to paint it in Red and then another click will paint it back to Black the text of the menu. So when its in Red its active chosen when its in Black its not working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your menuItem's `CheckOnClick` property to true

```
 yourToolStripMenuItem.CheckOnClick= true;
```

now when you click on it , it would be checked and unchecked automatically.